# Android - Catch RuntimeException during Instrumentation tests

Tags: java, android, exception, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

I am trying to set some instrumentation tests for some activities of a small Android application. I have successfully set some test classes, but I'm stuck with an issue : I can't seem to catch any Exceptions from my test methods.

Currently, I have an Activity which requires some parameters to be set, and throws a `RuntimeException` if those parameters are not set.
I have defined the following test class, to ensure that the Activity crashes if nothing is set :

```
public class DeviceWithoutMetadata extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<DeviceActivity_>
{
    public DeviceWithoutMetadata()
    {
        super(DeviceActivity_.class);
    }

    public void testCrashBecauseManifestPoorlyConfigured()
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.i("Beginning crash....");
            this.getActivity();
            Logger.i("Ending crash....");
        }
        catch (Throwable nmdre)
        {
            Logger.i("Absolutely normal to catch something here.");
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, `this.getActivity()` launches the Activity, and that would cause a `RuntimeException` to be thrown (and I want my test to tell me "That's OK, I got a `RuntimeException`as expected"). The problem is that I can see my "Beginning crash" log, but neither "Ending crash" nor "Absolutely normal..." logs. Instead, my test fails by telling me the following (lighten) stack trace :

```
MonitoringInstrumentation: Exception encountered by: com.axible.axcore.activities.DeviceActivity_@305a0bd. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
com.axible.axcore.exception.runtime.NoMetadataDefinedRuntimeException: The calling activity must define a <meta-data android:name="validation_scan_classname"> tag, that must contain the name of the class which will validate the scan of the Device ID.
at com.axible.axcore.activities.DeviceActivity.afterInject(DeviceActivity.java:36)
at com.axible.axcore.activities.DeviceActivity_.init_(DeviceActivity_.java:48)
at com.axible.axcore.activities.DeviceActivity_.onCreate(DeviceActivity_.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
```

I tried to catch the specific exception (`NoMetadataDefinedRuntimeException`, which extends `RuntimeException`), then `RuntimeException`, then `Exception`, then `Throwable`... I can't catch anything.

How can I catch this exception from my instrumentation tests ?